# yahoo mail api integration with oauth in php

Tags: yahoo

I have a strange requirement.

I need to read email from yahoo using php from my webapplication and store the user email in database

So is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: IMAP or POP might a good choice.

Comment: i want to fetch the different user email using their oauth token. Like a user come to my website he will register using yahoo mail and allow the offline access . i have to get their email to show the data in their account. can is it possible ?

Comment: Where you able to find the solution? Were you able to implement Yahoo IMAP support?

Answer (score 0):

It seems API access to Yahoo it's down ..
 The page https://developer.yahoo.com/mail/  states:
"Access to Yahoo’s IMAP service is one of the top requests from the application developer community. We are happy to announce that a Yahoo IMAP service with OAuth-2.0 will be available in early 2015. As announced on Dec 19th, 2014, we will no longer support the current Yahoo-customized Mail APIs after February 16, 2015. We will provide a migration path to this new service, which will allow us to better serve the developer community. For more information, send a mail to imap-service@yahoo-inc.com. "